# jQuery ajax is calling infinily , showing too much recursion error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am using jQuery.validationEngine plugin .I have a below ajax function to check duplicate unique value for a field.

```js
function _is_unique(caller) {
    var value = jQuery(caller).val();
    var field_id = jQuery(caller).attr('id');
    var field_name = jQuery(caller).attr('placeholder');

    if (value != '') {
        var uniqueObject = new Object();
        uniqueObject.field_id = field_id;
        uniqueObject.value = value;
        var uniqueString = JSON.stringify(uniqueObject);

        var getUrl = window.location;
        //console.log(getUrl);
        var baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseUrl + "/dashboard/check_unique",
            data: uniqueObject,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",

            success: function(msg) {
                if (msg == "exist") {
                    isError = true;
                    promptText += " This " + field_name + settings.allrules["is_unique"].alertText + "<br />";
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

if the field value is present in server then from server I am returnning "exist" else I am returning "notexist". 
Now while running my ajax script is calling infinitely . Can any please tell me what should I do to stop infinite loop of my ajax call.

**Edited**
This is the form Submit function . its also showing

> too much recursion

error in console. By any chance am I having problem here ?

```js
$('#searchform').on('submit', function(e){
      
         var validateError =''; 
    var id='';

    var fieldError = [];
    $('#searchform :input:text').each(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
       validateError =    jQuery.fn.validationEngine.loadValidation(document.getElementById(id));
      if(validateError)
      { fieldError.push(id); 
      
      }
      
    });
    if(fieldError.length!=0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else{
     $("form#searchform" ).submit();
     return true;
    }
  });
 
 });
```

Comment: Check PHP code if there is any infinite loop, use some tool like Chrome Postman or change _POST to _GET to manually test if PHP script is working. Also check if your server is not "lagging".

Comment: from php code if the value is not present it is retuning "notexist" . After having the response What I have seen using firebug console that the ajax url is hitting again and again. This same script is used in a form where I have multiple filed , there it is working fine. But I have form which has a  single field there I am facing this problem.

Comment: Also, dont you want to pass `uniqueString ` instead of `uniqueObject`? Your script might be failing because you are passing an object and not a string...

Comment: What I have read in the jquery api documentation that I can pass data as object.Thats why I have used uniqueObject and I am getting the values using $_POST in server.